# Please correct my code this is test bench for nand gate and i have some errors in it? please help me out

Tags: vhdl

ERROR:HDLCompiler:69 - "D:/xilinx program/and2/kj.vhd" Line 82:  is not declared.

ERROR:HDLCompiler:580 - "D:/xilinx program/and2/kj.vhd" Line 85: Mismatch on label ; expected behavior

ERROR:HDLCompiler:854 - "D:/xilinx program/and2/kj.vhd" Line 38: Unit  ignored due to previous errors.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity kj is
end kj;

architecture behavior of kj is

-- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

  component and2
    port(
      a : in  std_logic;
      b : in  std_logic;
      c : out std_logic
      );
  end component;

--Inputs
  signal a : std_logic := '0';
  signal b : std_logic := '0';
--signal clk : std_logic :='0';
--Outputs
  signal c : std_logic;
  -- No clocks detected in port list. Replace <clock> below with
  -- appropriate port name

begin

-- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
  uut : and2 port map (
    a => a,
    b => b,
    c => c
    );

  -- Clock process definitions
  -- Stimulus process
  a <= '0', '1' after 50 ns, '0' after 80 ns;
  b <= '0', '1' after 30 ns, '0' after 120 ns;
  process
  begin
    wait for 60 ns;
    assert(c = '1')
      report "output of and gate is incorrect"
      severity node;
  end process;
end kj;
```

Comment: I'm not very good at VHDL, but it is looking like you haven't really given us enough code here. What's the file you are working in here? And where is kj.vhd? It's complaining that you don't have some things defined.

Comment: Would be helpful with some information about what you have tried so far, and why some simple syntax error holds you back.

Comment: @BrantUnger:-this is the test bench i have written for a simple nand gate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues to correct in order to compile:

- Line 46: "node;" => "note;"
- Line 48: "end kj;" => "end behavior;"

Comment: hey thankx... would you suggest some resourses for writing test benches and simple vhdl language.I m a newbie to the vhdl

Comment: Google can point you to many useful small examples, and you can also look under [Wikipedia VHDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vhdl).  In particular I will suggest you get a copy of [The Designer's Guide to VHDL - 3rd edition](http://www.amazon.com/s?search-alias=stripbooks&field-isbn=0120887851), since it if very good as VHDL reference.  And most important: Do a lot of VHDL experiments using the simulator, so you get familiar with the language, and can fix simple errors yourself; otherwise you will never get ahead.